# Is Google Managed Prometheus billing per million or per billion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-managed-prometheus

The Google Managed Prometheus says that they cost $0.2 per million samples. However, in [pricing examples](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#sample-metering-examples) they say:

> Scenario 1: You have 100 containers, each writing 1,000 scalar times
> series.
>
> Variant A: If each time series is written every 15 seconds (1 sample/15s), then the number of samples written per month is 17,420,000,000 (175,200 samples/month * 1,000 time series * 100 containers), or 17.42 **million**.

But 17,420,000,000 is 17.42 **billion**. So in that example, the price should be $3600, not $3.60, which is a pretty big difference to a pocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed :)

[image]

Corrected documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#sample-metering-examples).

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this particular scenario is incorrect.
However, values in the table are correct - **18 million** metrics would cost approximately **$3.60**.
Errors in documentation can be reported using the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).
You can also use the [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=) to estimate cost of your metrics.

Comment: You saved my brain, I also didn't understand the example!!

Comment: I also had to read it three times - for some reason that many zeroes makes brain fuzzy ;P

Comment: What do you mean "scenario is incorrect"? "100 containers, each writing 1,000 scalar times series" is a pretty typical setup. It will generate numbers in billions, so it will cost $3600, not $3.6, right?